# How Do I retrieve most Recent record in different years With Date date in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, max

I'm working with a database that isn't structured that well and need to retrieve the row with the latest month used in specific years.  The main data is stored is stored in the member table and lists one row per member month. The Date for the member month is not specifically stored here but connected by a foreign Date_Key and linked to a Date table.  This is where the column for the Year and Month can be derived based on the Date_Key specified in each table. Each row in the Date table represents 1 new month for a year and each of these rows has a unique sequential date_key.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Studio as the environment

Member Table

| MemberKey | Membe_ID | Date_Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1234 | 89 |
| 101 | 1234 | 96 |
| 102 | 1234 | 97 |
| 103 | 1236 | 96 |
| 104 | 1236 | 97 |

Date Table

| Date_Key | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 89 | 2020 | 10 |
| 90 | 2020 | 11 |
| 91 | 2020 | 12 |
| 92 | 2021 | 1 |
| 93 | 2021 | 2 |
| 94 | 2021 | 3 |
| 95 | 2021 | 4 |
| 96 | 2021 | 5 |
| 97 | 2021 | 6 |

Looking for the following Results

| Member_ID | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2020 | 10 |
| 1234 | 2021 | 6 |
| 1236 | 2021 | 6 |

Answer (score 1):

2020/11 is NOT a date. It is a year/month pair. But it seems like a simple aggregate - select year, max(month) group by year. You join and include member ID so you include that column in the GROUP BY clause to get one row per member per year.

```
select mbr.Member_ID, dts.Year, max(dts.Month) as Month 
  from dbo.Members as mbr 
 inner join dbo.Dates as dts on mbr.Date_Key = dts.Date_Key
group by mbr.Member_ID, dts.Year
order by mbr.Member_ID, dts.Year
;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried something similar to this and this method however, I have also since been asked to bring in a 4th field in the member  group field  so when there are 2 groups in 1 year they would like to see the most recent group of the latest month in the year.